# How much time hold Cricket if Match delayed from Rain?

Tags: cricket, officiating, interruption

I am really very confuse, How much to wait if  Match delayed from Rain?

If rain delay game from first inning?
if rain delay game from second inning?

What is the procedure 20/20 over, one day and test Matches? any rules for this?

Let us Assume:

if Team A scored: 181 all out(41.5 over), Now

Team B played: Rain occurs at 121/3 (27.4 over). If rain Delayed from local time 4:12 PM. 
How much time to wait if rain not stopped? Any idea??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Laws: 3.8, 3.9](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws-in-action/law-3-in-action/), the match will be resumed if rain gets stopped within game time, light and weather conditions are good and ground and pitch get suitable to resume match.

So it depends on total time allocated for that single game. In a T20 match, time allocated for a single innings is usually 100 minutes and for ODI, time for a single innings allocated  is 3.5 hours. So, approximately 4 hours are usually allocated for a single T20 match and 8 hours for a single ODI match.

If rain gets stopped within time, umpires check how much time for that game has been left (excluding drinks and innings breaks) and how much overs can be bowled in that time according to 14 overs per hour. The match would be then resumed according to revised reduced overs.

Umpires apply [D/L Method](http://www.dlmethod.co.uk/) to update scores to compensate overs reduction whether its first innings or second innings of the match.

If rain doesn't stop within game time then there are two cases; If rain interrupts in second innings of the match, then D/L method would declare winner of the match otherwise if rain interrupts the match before second innings gets started, then the match would be considered as draw.